# Is it possible to automatically snap polygons in the same layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, snapping

there are similar questions but I still couldn't figure out if it's possible to do this in QGIS.

I have a layer with categorized point data (3 categories), I use minimum bounding box/convex hull in order to create 3 polygons automatically covering these 3 categories. It does create the polygons but I need those polygons' adjacent lines to snap to each other. How could I achieve this? I tried many snapping tools but I couldn't find a tool that snaps polygons to each other in the same layer.

[Two Polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ezx2.png)

[image: Tolerance]

[image: Behavior]

Comment: You can snap features in the same layer using the Processing>Snap Geometries to Layer plugin.  Just choose the same layer for Input and Reference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm attaching screenshots to my original question. Somehow Snap Geometries to Layer plugin doesn't work for me, maybe I'm doing something wrong. In the first screenshot there are two polygons. I'm also attaching screenshots of a warning that suggests me to reproject (I can't) and third one is the options. Which of these options would suit my application?

thanks in advance again!

Comment: I think the snap tolerance is to high.  Use View>Measure>MeasureLine (configured to measure map units, degrees) and check the distance between some of the points that you want to snap.  Use a slightly larger value as a starting point for the snap tolerance and make adjustments as needed.  Based on the image you provided I would start with 'Prefer aligning nodes, don't insert new vertices' as the snap behavior (since from your image it appears that you want to snap long, straight boundaries of roughly the same length).

Comment: Thank you for your follow up reply. I believe I'm describing what I'm trying to achieve wrong. This tool snaps the entire polygons on top of each other (am I correct?) What I want to achieve is to snap only closest boundaries from these two polygons. These are two separate fields and polygons are created automatically from point data using minimum bounding geometry. In real life these two fields don't have any space between them. But since I create the polygons using minimum bounding geometry it also creates a gap between these two polygons. Do you think I'm fiddling with the right tool?